# Disallow Resizing of Buttons in Excel Worksheet (VBA)

Tags: excel, vba, button

I have created a macro that adds two buttons to every worksheet in my workbook. I am trying to figure out how "lock" the buttons (via VBA) so that the user cannot resize, change text, etc. This seems like it should be a simple task but for some reason, I cannot find a concise answer. The only code I found is: `.Placement = xlMove`, however, this does not work.

Here is the current button code:

```
Dim t1 As Range
Set t1 = ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(TwoDown, 6), Cells(TwoDown, 6))
Set btn1 = ActiveSheet.Buttons.Add(t1.Left, t1.Top, t1.Width, t1.Height)

With btn1
    .Placement = xlMove
    .OnAction = "Module32.btnF"
    .Caption = "Sort By Field Order"
     .Name = "Sort By Field Order"
End With

t1.Select
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

Thanks in advance & Merry Christmas!

Comment: Can you just protect the sheet, not allowing the user to edit objects?

Comment: Unfortunately, if I add "ws.Protect" to the end of the aforementioned code, I receive a "Run-time error '1004': You cannot use this command on a protected sheet". The line of code highlighted in the debug is: "NextFreeF = Range("B7:B" & Rows.Count).Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Row" which is part of the "Module32.btnF" button macro that does the sort.

Comment: You have to specify the protection options - you probably only want `DrawingObjects:=True` and the other options to be `False` or `True` as applicable. See [`Worksheet.Protect`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.protect) for more info.

Comment: I tried "ws.Protect DrawingObjects:=True" and received the same error.

Comment: You have to check if sheet is protected first.

Comment: Sorry, do you mean that I should specifically set every option to "False" but set "DrawingObjects:= True"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK, the only way to do this is to protect the sheet, with `DrawingObjects:=True` and all other options with `False` or `True` as desired.

```
ws.Protect DrawingObjects:=True, Contents:=False, Scenarios:= _
        False, AllowFormattingCells:=True, AllowFormattingColumns:=True, _
        AllowFormattingRows:=True, AllowInsertingColumns:=True, AllowInsertingRows _
        :=True, AllowInsertingHyperlinks:=True, AllowDeletingColumns:=True, _
        AllowDeletingRows:=True, AllowSorting:=True, AllowFiltering:=True, _
        AllowUsingPivotTables:=True
```

Note that you'll have to `Unprotect` the sheet before trying to add buttons, if it's already protected.

---

**Side note**: A `Button` also has a `Locked` and `LockedText` property, but these are only in effect *if the worksheet is protected*. Setting them to `False` allows the button to be edited when the worksheet is *in Design mode* (but still protected). As mentioned earlier, I think the only way to accomplish what you're looking for is by protecting the sheet.